# scrapy selector string won't accept international characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

I'm trying to get a Scrapy spider to crawl a website but one of the elements I need for the items I want is written in Spanish, using a vowel with a tilde (í).

titulo=title.select(u'.//["Título Original:"]/text()'.extract()

I've found similar issues here but the answers accepted for them didn't work for me.

Adding the u at the beginning of the string took care of some of the problems but gives me the error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I found other questions here suggesting using '.../text()'.decode('utf-8) but doing so or  using .encode('utf-8') instead gives me the error

```
    exceptions.ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

Is there something I'm missing or some other way or am I better off crafting a regex to catch every other part of my string but that letter?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
 def parse(self, response):
    #change the response to an HtmlResponse to allow for utf-8 encoding of the body.
response = HtmlResponse(url=response.url, status=response.status, headers=response.headers, body=response.body)

print '\n\nresponse encoding', response.encoding ##the page is encoded in utf-8

hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select('//div[@class="datosespectaculo"]')

    items = []
    for title in titles:          
        item = CarteleraItem()
        titulo=title.select(u'.//["Título Original:"]/text()'.encode('utf-8')).extract()
        Ano=title.select('.//span[@itemprop="copyrightYear"]/text').extract()
        item ["title"] = titulo
        item ["Ano"] = Ano   
        items.append(item)
```

And here's the source for the webpage for reference

```
<div id="contgeneral">
<div class="contyrasca">
<div id="contfix">
<div class="contespectaculo">

<div class="colizq"><div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Movie">
<h1 class="titulo" itemprop="name">15.361</h1>

<img class="afiche" src="http://www.cartelera.com.uy/imagenes_espectaculos/musicdetail13/14770.jpg"/>
<div class="datosespectaculo">

<strong>Título Original:</strong> <em>15.361</em><br />

<strong>Año: </strong><span itemprop="copyrightYear">2014</span><br />
<strong>Género: </strong><span itemprop="genre">Comedia/Drama</span><br />
<strong>Duración: </strong><span itemprop="duration">60&#39;</span><br />
<strong>Calificación: </strong>+18 años<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

If `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` doesn't work, you can use a unicode string where non-ASCII characters use the `\u` escape sequence.

So you XPath selector becomes:

```
titulo=title.select(u'.//["T\u00edtulo Original:"]/text()'.encode('utf-8')).extract()
```

I usually use a simple Python shell session to check the escape sequence:

```
paul@wheezy:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> u'.//["Título Original:"]/text()'
u'.//["T\xedtulo Original:"]/text()'
>>> u'.//["T\u00edtulo Original:"]/text()'
u'.//["T\xedtulo Original:"]/text()'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to the start of your python file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

For full explanation, [read the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code).

Comment: Yep. See http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code

Comment: Thanks @pault., added the link to the answer.

Comment: I tried this already (forgot to say, sorry), it didn't solve the problem.